# How to reload only a userscript, i.e. without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts, reloading

I'm working on a Greasemonkey userscript for a web app that *needs configuration steps* before I can actually test my userscript's functionality. So every time I reload the page – to refresh my userscript from the updated file –, I have to reconfigure the web app before testing. Needless to say, this gets old very quickly.

Is there a way to **reload only the userscript**, preferably from the userscript itself? I would want to e.g. bind the reload to a keyboard shortcut.

I thought that this must be a very common need, but I came up empty-handed when trying to find a solution.

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/q/10700127/526704

Comment: (1) If you don't use `GM_` functions, **do all of your dev in the console.**  Only when the code works, put it in a script.  (2) Even with GM funcs, can usually test most of the code in the console. (3) **Make a separate user script that does all of the configuration steps automatically.** (4) If you are really into pain, make your script AJAX in new code and `eval()` it *in the script scope*. Don't even think about this unless your script relies heavily on `GM_` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Generally not feasible.**

As one of the collaborators remarked on [this issue](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1469) in GreaseMonkey's GitHub repo, almost all scripts mutate the page in ways that makes repeated script execution problematic.

I overlooked this fact in my original question – my script *does* mutate the page in ways that makes repeated script execution problematic.

**If you want to implement script reload**, and you find a feasible method to do that:

- make sure you carefully evaluate what effect will it have on the page, and
- implement clean-up code to prepare the page for the repeated execution of your script.

Comment: Well, of course the script needs to handle this correctly; but your answer still doesn't say how to reload the script even if it would be able to cope with that.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to have alook into AJAX for this then, it's a tool that interacts with databases without refreshing the webpage. I.E - dynamic webpages.

Might help, just do a general google browse and see if it applies.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp